# How to edit or open existing Angular Library

Tags: angular, angular-library

i would like to overwrite an existing Angular library for customization. now i am using Visual studio for development process. i tried by opening a Angular library using Visual Studio but its not opening .Please help me how to open an existing  library in visual studio. Thanks

Comment: An angular library like.... Material.. or one that you or someone else developed? From where are you opening the library. And what do you mean by open a Library?

Comment: when you install a library this is in the folder `node_modules`. So you can edit the .ts, but check it there're another way to customize. e.g. if it's only change the .css try write the .css in the `styles.css` to override, or check the library to look for options. You can also, generally look for the code of the library in github and clone/edit the library and install it after change it or use the code to create simples components